# jQuery Datables retrieve Array from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using the jQuery DataTables Select plugin to select multiple rows from a table and store their data inside an array. Then I am making an Ajax Request in order to pass the array to another php file. The problem is that I can not fetch the data from the request.

Since AJAX calls can transfer only text I converted the array to a JSON sting but I had no luck fetching the data.

my dataTable.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.5.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.5.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<title>JQuery DataTable</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Case</td>
            <td>num</td>
            <td>is</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Case</td>
            <td>num</td>
            <td>is</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button id="process-button">Process Selected Rows</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    select: true
  });
  
  // This array will store the data of the selected rows
  var selectedRows = [];
  
  // When a row is selected, its data is added to the 'selectedRows' array
  table.on('select', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
    var rowData = table.rows(indexes).data().toArray();
    selectedRows = selectedRows.concat(rowData);
    console.log(selectedRows);
  });
  
  // When a row is deselected, its data is removed from the 'selectedRows' array
  table.on('deselect', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
    var rowData = table.rows(indexes).data().toArray();
    selectedRows = selectedRows.filter(function(r) {
      return rowData.indexOf(r) === -1;
    });
    console.log(selectedRows);
  });
  
  // This function sends the 'selectedRows' array to the 'process.php' script using an AJAX request
  function processRows() {
  // Convert the 'selectedRows' array to a JSON string
  var selectedRowsJSON = JSON.stringify(selectedRows);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: { selectedRows: selectedRowsJSON },
    success: function() {
    // Redirect the user to the 'process.php' file
    window.location.href = 'process.php';
    }
  });
}

  $('#process-button').click(function() {
  processRows();
  });
  
});
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

My process.php file

```
<?php
// Check if the 'selectedRows' JSON string was received in the request
if (isset($_POST['selectedRows'])) {
  // Convert the 'selectedRows' JSON string into an array
  $selectedRows = json_decode($_POST['selectedRows'], true);

  // Do something with the 'selectedRows' array here
  foreach ($selectedRows as $row) {
    $column1 = $row[0];
    $column2 = $row[1];
    $column3 = $row[2];
    $column4 = $row[3];
    
    echo $column1;
    echo $column2;
    echo $column3;
    echo $column4;
  }
} else {
  // Handle the case where the 'selectedRows' array was not received
  echo 'Array not received.';
}
?>
```

(Updated - according to comment on Rohit K. answer)
I used the same php code with the one you provided My refactored script looks like this

```
var selectedRowsJSON = JSON.stringify(selectedRows); 
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "process.php", data: { selectedRows: selectedRowsJSON }, success: function(response) { let data = JSON.parse(response); } });
```

In the console I am getting this error now ->

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1
> column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['selectedRows'])) {
  $selectedRows = json_decode($_POST['selectedRows'], true);
  foreach ($selectedRows as $row) {
    return json_encode(
        array(
            "column1" => $row[0],
            "column2" => $row[1],
            "column3" => $row[2],
            "column4" => $row[3],
        )
    );
    break;
  }
} else {
  return json_encode(['message' => 'Array not received.']);
}
?>
```

This will return json encoded string back to ajax as response and
and on ajax success try this

```
success: function(response) {
    let result = JSON.parse(response);
}
```

this will convert json string to object

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I refactored my code based on your answer but I my code is still not working. I used the same php code with the one you provided My refactored script looks like this 
  
var selectedRowsJSON = JSON.stringify(selectedRows);
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: { selectedRows: selectedRowsJSON },
    success: function(response) {
      let data = JSON.parse(response);
    }
  });

In the console I am getting this error now -> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.